# MySQL distinguish between two cases depending on a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, union

I have a query which returns all events for a given user. But first, it searches for the user in a subquery given user's mobile number.

```
SELECT e.user_id, e.id FROM events e 
WHERE e.user_id = (SELECT u.user_id FROM users u WHERE u.mobile = '88888888')
```

If there is no user with that mobile number 0 rows will be returned. If the user exists but there are no events 0 rows will be returned as well. I would like to be able to differentiate between those two cases. Any idea how I could do that in a **one** query?

Here is my approach:

```
(SELECT (SELECT u.user_id FROM users u WHERE u.mobile = '88888888'), NULL)
UNION
(SELECT e.user_id, e.id FROM events e  
WHERE e.user_id = (SELECT u.user_id FROM users u WHERE u.mobile = '88888888'))
```

In that way I know that I will always have at least one row which just checks if the user exists. So if user_id in the first row is NULL means that there is no user and if it is not NULL means the user exists. But I do not like this solution because user search subquery is repeated twice and significantly slower then just the first query. Any ideas for a faster solution?

Comment: What output do you actually want?  Do you want all events, all users, or both?

Comment: If the user for the given mobile number exists and has events I want those events. Otherwise, I want to be able to distinguish between the case when there are 0 events or user does not exist. As long as I can achieve it from my application code which will run that query and get back a result object I am happy. I gave one example of prepending one additional row to the results which allows for that. But I am open to any other suggestions. I am not too proficient with sql, throwing an error if user does not exist could be an option for example. Or returning different columns for those two cases.

Comment: Among other ideas I had was for example to use variable to store the result of the subquery and not execute it twice. However, I do not know how variables e.g. `@usr` behave in terms of concurrency - would those operations still be atomic? Could it cause conflicts if other query on this db also defined @usr variable?

Comment: _Don't_ try something like this, you can just do a single query with a join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a single result set which will show all events *and* users, regardless of whether an event maps to a user or vice-versa, then you can try a simulated full outer join:

```
SELECT COALESCE(u.user_id, 'NA'),
       COALESCE(e.id, 'NA')
FROM events e
LEFT JOIN users u ON e.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE u.mobile = '88888888'
UNION ALL
SELECT COALESCE(u.user_id, 'NA'),
       COALESCE(e.id, 'NA')
FROM events e
RIGHT JOIN users u ON e.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE u.mobile = '88888888'
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use a full outer join which will return results from both the tables

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp